# Unity - saving simple data off device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

First off, I am developing a game for mobile, android and ios. I am currently focusing on android, hence why my main focus on data saving has been with Google Play and not Game Center.

I am not referring to a high score value, but a value that could go up or down. Like if you earn gold in a game and then spend some of the gold in the game, then you would want the latest value, not the highest.

I already have Google Play working in my game and it works fine for achievements, but the leaderboard doesn't work very well, or doesn't work for my need.  An example of this is that the leaderboard seems to be down right now.

I know I could go the route of firebase and setup an account and write info that way, but that seems like a bit of overkill for what I want to store - just one integer value per user, off device, that can be retrieved quickly and written to quickly.

I don't want to use encrypted playprefs for the obvious reasons.

I'm sure this issue has been ran into a million times before. I'm just curious how the unity community has solved this issue. I would love to get it working in some kind of Google Play Leaderboard setup, but it just doesn't seem to work consistently.

Comment: most games save "gold/coins/etc" locally, the ones that doesn't use an owned server for it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That may be my solution in the end, but that wouldn't be persistent if I moved devices and also it could be hacked.

Comment: Looks like there's more options on Google Play that I'm not using.  I'm going to look more into it.  Leaderboard isn't working for me at this point, so I have to find something else.  I'll update this thread when I have a solution.

Comment: Rent a server, connect to it and post your score or data. You are in control with this and can do whatever you want with it. You can add any feature you want unlike Google Play

Comment: Gonna take me a little to tweak it into my project, but here's the solution I'm going with:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/894995/how-to-saveload-with-google-play-services.html

Comment: Also, I don't know why this is marked as duplicate.  I only posted it once, then edited it.